# Using useRef and useEffect to store to variables once on mount with functional component

Tags: reactjs

I have multiple instances of the same component on a page, and I want to give an unique ID to each. Usually in a class component I would declare a this. instance variable, in componentDidMount() set the variable using cuid(), and in the render method reference it.

Now, attempting this in a React functional component and trying to reference it using id.current in the return does not seem to be giving me the expected result. Some components still have a null id. Am I missing anything?

```
  const id = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    id.current = cuid();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply pass `cuid()` as argument to `useRef`.

```
const id = useRef(cuid());
```

This will store a unique id in `id` variable, which will be created only once on mount.

`useEffect` with an empty dependency is like a `componentDidMount` that will run after the render. Hence, setting `id` there would result in not being available during initial render.